# Setting timeout on blocking I/O ops with ServerSocketChannel doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, socketchannel

I'm working on a small group conversation server in Java and I'm currently hacking network code, but it seems like I cannot set right timeout on blocking I/O ops: chances are I've been bitten by some Java weirdness (or, simply, I misinterpret javadoc).

So, this is the pertinent code from `ConversationServer` class (with all security checks and logging stripped for simplicity):

```
class ConversationServer {

    // ...

    public int setup() throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port), Settings.MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS + 1);

        server.socket().setSoTimeout((int) Settings.AWAIT_PLAYERS_MS);

        int numberOfPlayers;

        for (numberOfPlayers = 0; numberOfPlayers < Settings.MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS; ++numberOfPlayers) {
            SocketChannel clientSocket;

            try {
                clientSocket = server.accept();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException timeout) {
                break;
            }

            clients.add(messageStreamFactory.create(clientSocket));
        }

        return numberOfPlayers;
    }

    // ...

}
```

The expected behaviour is to let connect `Settings.MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS` clients at most, or terminate setup anyway after `Settings.AWAIT_PLAYER_MS` milliseconds (currently, `30000L`).

What happens, is that if I connect `Settings.MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS` clients, everything is fine (exit because of `for` condition), but if I don't, the `SocketTimeoutException` I'd expect is never thrown and the server hangs forever.

If I understand right, `server.socket().setSoTimeout((int) Settings.AWAIT_PLAYERS_MS);` should be sufficient, but it doesn't give the expected behaviour.

So, can anyone spot the error here?

Comment: Good question... According to the javadoc that should work.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't time out for me when run with IDEA on 64-bit JDK 1.7.0_21 or a JDK8 build from a few weeks ago in Win 7.

Comment: ...and the same in an Ubuntu server with OpenJDK 1.7.0_21 directly from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the timeout works if you change from

```
server.socket().setSoTimeout((int) Settings.AWAIT_PLAYERS_MS);
server.accept();
```

to

```
server.socket().setSoTimeout((int) Settings.AWAIT_PLAYERS_MS);
server.socket().accept();
```

I.e. call `accept()` on the same object on which you set the SO timeout. I don't know enough about NIO sockets to say exactly what results from doing this. Maybe somebody else can shed some light.

Comment: In this case, though, the result will be a `Socket`; you'll have to `.getChannel()` on it to get a `SocketChannel`. Strangely enough, since 1.7, you have a `.setOption()` on a `SocketChannel` but no way of setting the timeout:/

Comment: The `.socket().accept().getChannel()` workaround works well. Then it was a Java-weirdness (sadly)! It's a bit upsetting that people report this happening on JDK8 too. I mean, is the use of NIO so rare?